# Inner join from 3 tables in one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables :

```
tb_document
============================
|document_id|document_title|
============================
|     1     |        A     |
|     2     |        B     |
|     3     |        C     |
============================

tb_wrapper_scho                  tb_wrapper_li
=============================    =============================
|id_scho|data_title|doc_name|    |id_sli |data_title|doc_name|
=============================    =============================
|   1   |  TitleA  |   A    |    |   1   |  TitleB  |   B    |
|   2   |  TitleC  |   C    |    =============================
=============================
```

I wanna get `data_title` from `tb_wrapper_scho` and `tb_wrapper_li` where has same `doc_name` with `document_title` in `tb_document` in one result `$title`

here's the query :

```
SELECT
      tb_document.document_title,
      tb_wrapper_scho.data_title,
      tb_wrapper_scho.doc_name,
      tb_wrapper_li.data_title,
      tb_wrapper_li.doc_name
FROM
      INNER JOIN tb_wrapper_scho ON tb_document.document_title = tb_wrapper_scho.doc_name
      INNER JOIN tb_wrapper_li ON tb_document.document_title = tb_wrapper_li.doc_name
WHERE 
      document_id = '$doc_id'
```

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $title = $row['data_title'];
     print_r($title);
}
```

It gives me blank result. Help me, please.. thank you :)

Comment: something's missing after the FROM...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `tb_document` table in the `FROM` clause. Try this instead:

```
SELECT
      d.document_title,
      s.data_title,
      s.doc_name,
      i.data_title,
      i.doc_name
FROM  tb_document d
      INNER JOIN tb_wrapper_scho s ON d.document_title = s.doc_name
      INNER JOIN tb_wrapper_li i ON d.document_title =i.doc_name
WHERE 
      document_id = '$doc_id'
```

Comment: Ad if you need doc_name to be different in one of them you can use the 'as' keyword and a new name for the column after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      tb_document.document_title,
      tb_wrapper_scho.data_title,
      tb_wrapper_scho.doc_name,
      tb_wrapper_li.data_title,
      tb_wrapper_li.doc_name
FROM tb_document
      left outer JOIN tb_wrapper_scho ON tb_document.document_title = tb_wrapper_scho.doc_name
      left outer JOIN tb_wrapper_li ON tb_document.document_title = tb_wrapper_li.doc_name
WHERE 
      document_id = '$doc_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have idea, would you like it:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM tb_document as tbDoc INNER JOIN tb_wrapper_scho as tbScho
  ON tbDoc.document_title = tbScho.doc_name
UNION
  SELECT * FROM tb_document as tbDoc INNER JOIN tb_wrapper_li as tblI
  ON tbDoc.document_title = tblI.doc_name)threeTableJoin ORDER BY `document_id` ASC
```

Only that, Good luck friend !

Answer (score 0):

As your tables contains column with same name so at time of retrieving data using alias you must change column name to distinct name. so that result array must contain unique index for each value. so your query must be as

```
SELECT 
      d.document_title as document_title,
      s.data_title as scho_data_title,
      s.doc_name as scho_doc_name,
      li.data_title as li_data_title,
      li.doc_name as li_data_name
FROM
      tb_document d
      LEFT JOIN tb_wrapper_scho s ON d.document_title = s.doc_name
      LEFT JOIN tb_wrapper_li li ON li.doc_name = d.document_title 
WHERE 
      d.document_id = '$doc_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      tb_document.document_title,
      tb_wrapper_scho.data_title,
      tb_wrapper_scho.doc_name,
      tb_wrapper_li.data_title,
      tb_wrapper_li.doc_name

FROM tb_document AS tb_document

    LEFT JOIN tb_wrapper_scho AS tb_wrapper_scho ON (tb_wrapper_scho.doc_name=tb_document.document_title)
    LEFT JOIN tb_wrapper_li AS tb_wrapper_li ON (tb_wrapper_li.doc_name=tb_document.document_title)

WHERE tb_document.document_id = intval($doc_id);
```

Any good?

Also can you check the result of mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array() should return TRUE.